# When should I create classes in order to avoid huge main method?

Tags: java, class, javafx-2

Just a question from a noob: how do I avoid huge `main` (in case of JavaFX, `start`) methods? I tend to create one-class projects but I know that's incorrect. Basically I do not know when to create dedicated classes for specific tasks.

I hope this question is not so stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a not a stupid question.  From what you've said, you might not need other classes. You may just need methods.
Lets look at a simple example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 4 + 2;
        System.out.println(4 + 2);
    }
}
```

Easy, right?  But now, what if it gets harder.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int k = i + (7 / 2) * 3 / 14;
            System.out.println(i + " " + k);
        }
    }
}
```

Now obviously, this isn't actually harder.  But notice how there is a pattern?  We take every number 0-9, and add `(7 / 2) * 3 / 14`.  This can be moved into a method:

```
 int getNumber(int i) {
     return i + (7 / 2) * 3 / 14);
 }
```

Now, our code looks much cleaner, as we don't have to deal with any addition or division or multiplication

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int k = getNumber(i);
            System.out.println(i + " " + k);
        }
    }
}
```

This example might seem dumb, because it involves a very easy math problem, but the point is: **If you have something that you do repeatedly, put it in a method.**

Note:
Methods can also be used to split up a large function.  **When in doubt, divide and conquer!**
See this:

```
void run() {
    getInput();
    tick();
    render();
}
```

Is much cleaner than something like this:

```
 void run() {
     Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
     String string = reader.nextString();
     MyObject obj = new MyObject();
     obj.doSomething(string);
     obj.render();
 }
```

If you looked at that code you'd have no idea what it was doing!  But the first example you would, because it divides into methods that clearly identify what they do.

---

Anyway, about classes:
Google OOP! There are tons of great resources.  For most classes, you can think of them as a container.  You could create a class, `Wallet`, that would contain `Coin`s and manipulate it (think `spend`, `remove`, `add`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no stupid question :)

You ask about Oriented Object Programming concept.

In Java, C++ or Php Object, the purpose is to store your code into logical aera. Immagine your code like life. Immagine everything act like an object.

For example, your program is simulating car.

In your code you will have an class Car, then a class Engine, then class BMW that inherit from Car and Car who is containing a instance of Engine.

In internet (use google) you will find a lots of explanation about how OOP work. All of this will explain this much better than i will.

If you have any question, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my opinion that I've developed over the course of learning to program. Though my background is moreso with perl scripting and not oop

Separate the presentation from the data/logic.

Meaning, everything should be in classes (or function), and from the main thread you merely pass the object (or function) data, and you get data the same way.

If it does a specific set of tasks, make a class out of it.

If it could be used for other purposes make a class out of it.

If it does a specific operation, make a function out of it.